# How to use .where NULL in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have items in a table that have `:parent_id` that are empty to signify it being a main category. I was wondering how to iterate over these using `.where` (if that's even the right method to call).

Here's my controller:

```
def new
  @title = 'New Post';
  @post = Post.new
  @categories = BlogCategory.all
  @cat_zero = BlogCategory.where(:parent_id NULL)
  @cat_one = BlogCategory.where(parent_id: 1)
  @cat_two = BlogCategory.where(parent_id: 2)
  @cat_three = BlogCategory.where(parent_id: 3)
  @cat_four = BlogCategory.where(parent_id: 4)
end
```

The rest works fine, it's just that NULL isn't working. (The relationship between BlogCategory and Post have been made.)

I have tried doing these, but with no fortune (and a few other versions of these):

```
@cat_zero = BlogCategory.where(:parent_id == NULL)
@cat_zero = BlogCategory.where(:parent_id.nil?)
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spelling you're looking for is:

```
@cat_zero = BlogCategory.where(parent_id: nil)
```

It's just the same as the spelling for other values, only using `nil`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for this but it's raising an errorr: `syntax error, unexpected keyword_nil, expecting ')' @cat_zero = BlogCategory.where(:parent_id nil) ^`

Comment: Wow, such a silly mistake when trying out different combinations, I didn't realise it was still like that! Thank you for pointing this out.